# ES6 features in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Where could I find the list of ES6 features taht are ready to use in React Native?

Eg Object.assign().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's depends on what JSX done (see [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)). You can use [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) for more ES6 feature, [this post](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#react-native-with-babel-and-webpack) maybe helps.

[EDIT]
According this [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#content), full support table is here:

### ES5

```jsx
// Reserved Words: 
promise.catch(function() { });
```

### ES6

```jsx
// Arrow function: 
<C onPress={() => this.setState({pressed: true})}

// Call spread: 
Math.max(...array);

// Class: 
class C extends React.Component { render() { return <View />; }

// Destructuring: 
var {isActive, style} = this.props;

// Iteration: 
for (var element of array) { }

// Computed Properties: 
var key = 'abc'; var obj = {[key]: 10};

// Object Consise Method: 
var obj = { method() { return 10; } };

// Object Short Notation: 
var name = 'vjeux'; var obj = { name };

// Rest Params: 
function(type, ...args) { }

// Template: 
var who = 'world'; var str = `Hello ${who}`;
```

### ES7

```jsx
// Object Spread: 
var extended = { ...obj, a: 10 };

// Function Trailing Comma: 
function f(a, b, c,) { }
```

Comment: Apart from that, do you know which JS VM is used in React Native?

Comment: it's JavaScriptCore on iOS

Comment: In Android for some strange reason some features work IF you have the chrome dev tools opened debugging the app. That means you have to be careful while trying to use that stuff because it might work while in development and later breaks when trying to build for production.

Answer (score 1):

React Native is using the Babel transpiler - the features it enables are all of [Babel Core](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js), plus whatever is whitelisted in `/packager/transformer.js`.